# Minimize DOM access inorder to have a more responsive page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tree-nodes

Accessing DOM elements with JavaScript is slow so in order to have a more responsive page, we have to do the following things

1. Cache references to accessed elements
2. Update nodes "offline" and then add them to the tree
3. Avoid fixing layout with JavaScript

Can anyone tell me how to do the first two things?

Thank You

Comment: It's not really *browser caching*. You're storing a reference to the element, e.g., `var cacheref = document.getElementById('someId');` Or `var othercacheref = document.createElementById('div');` Then you can do things like `cacheref.appendChild(othercacheref);` without having to go *get* the element's DOM reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some abstract questions, ones even that do not necessarily relate to each other.

---

**1. Cache references to accessed elements**

Caching references is a *practice* and sometimes a *necessity*. The *act* of maintaining a reference to an element locally (or, um, globally) is rather simple. When working with DOM methods like `document.createElement()`, there's usually a variable it's saved to. This is a reference that may be *cached* for later use. `document.getElementById` returns a reference to an element, `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a list of references, as does `document.querySelectorAll`, etc.

---

**2. Update nodes "offline" and then add them to the tree**

When you say "offline", I'm not quite sure the context you're referencing. Is this before whatever element (including a string like `<div>`) is added to the DOM?

There are three primary ways to interact with elements:

- `document.createElement` (with `elem.appendChild`)

  There was a day in the somewhat distant past when this was the *de rigueur* way of monkeying with your page content. It appealed to the subset of the "web developer" community which was comfortable with an API-like, programmatic way of addressing and manhandling the DOM and it's denizens; it almost *looked like real code*, the hard stuff.

  Sure, some of the code kinda rambled, and iteratively creating and appending and appending to those and on and on looked wicked-cool to anyone who *didn't have to birth it*.

  If you were clever with [`cloneNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4), you could get more reasonable results with DOM nodes. But I *think* until the last few years, `cloneNode` wasn't a great option. I may misremember that, cargo-cult and all. Correct me if I'm wrong.

  Then IE came along and gave us...
- [`elem.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)

  Surprise! This was *non-standard, man*. How *could* they? The only problem was, *it was really fast*. [Killer-fast](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) (like IE6/7 never happened either, we all want to forget).

  DOM was... whatever, browsers were slow and inefficient and *weren't really running real code anyways*, so DOM's slowness was tolerated. But then, for whatever reason, `innerHTML` entered stage-left and groovy, dude, it was *faster than DOM methods*. And elegant, in "I like staring at markup instead of DOM methods all day" way.

  Eventually, everyone got on the `.innerHTML` bandwagon, and it's now a de facto standard. It's fast, right?

  Well. Depends. Doing `elem.innerHTML = "<p>Hey!</p>"` was fast, yep. So was `elem.innerHTML = '<p>Hey!</p><p>Yo!</p><p>What!</p>'`. So naturally folks thought, it's a property, let's get giggy and

  ```
  for 1..500 element.innerHTML += '<p>Medusa!</p>';
  ```

  Psuedo-code there. Where's the problem? `+=` is like *kryptonite* to our sprinty friend, `innerHTML`. Crazy-bad, never-do-it, don't-even-think-about-it bad idea. Why? AFAIK, it has to do with the manner in which `.innerHTML` assaults the inner content, so when you `elem.innerHTML += '...mayhem...'`, you're "tearing down" the DOM each time. Or something. Which makes the DOM weep.

  Don't make the DOM cry.
- [`documentFragment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A3)

  So then at some point (has it always been there? DOM Level 3, if that means anything), `documentFragment` crashed the scene. MDN's [*brief* note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment) about it sums it up, though. It's a `Node` separate from the main DOM. Like a little box you put stuff in, before moving it to the daddy DOM.

  In terms of *speed*, it's right behind `.innerHTML` for the most part, and is all DOM-programmy and stuff. Nifty.

---

In terms of caching, much of that has to do with how you structure your code and use scope to your advantage. Take for example:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var target = document.getElementById('target'),
      source = document.getElementById('source'),
      ...

  source.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var words = source.getElementsByTagName('span'),
        total = words.length,
        word;

    while (word = words[--total]) {
      target.appendChild(word);
    }
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/T6YLZ/

I keep the `target` and `source` above the `click` handler's scope, so that when I access them later, I already have them. Since I don't add the `words` to `source` until `window.onload`, I won't get all of the `span` elements with the `words` to move to `target` until `source.click` occurs.

You seem to be describing `documentFragment`s in your terminology. And they're cool. I've only recently come across them, although apparently for those in the know they seem to have been there for a couple years or more. So if you're one of those `must.use.dom.methods(now)`, use `documentFragment`s before inserting into the non-fragment DOM.

However... Keep in mind there are times you will use `elemn.innerHTML`, because you're adding markup. Maybe you have templates, AJAX response markup, whatnot.

Just don't `+=` when `elem.innerHTML`ing.